# Is there any way I can create/get and return a Class<T<?, ?>> object?

Tags: java, generics

I seem to have painted myself in to a bit of a generics coloured corner. Basically I have a generic Interface `X<T1, T2 extends Y<?, ?>>` with a bunch of methods, including a `T1 getFirstClass()`, and a `T2 getSecondClass()`. This works fine for most things, but one of the things I need to do with this is find instances of this Class that are super classes of what I'm looking up, and I need a "catch-all" object for those that can't be found. This means I end up with a Class that looks like:

```
public class A implements X<Object, Y<?, ?>> {
    ...
    public Class<Y<?, ?>> getSecondClass() {
        return ????
    }
}
```

I tried dealing with this by ignoring the `<?, ?>` bit and using `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")`, which works in Eclipse, but when built by ant, gives the error message `type parameter Y is not within its bound`. The JDK **should** be the same - I'm only aware of one being installed on my system, namely 1.6.0_23 (I unfortunately can't update this due to factors beyond my control).

Is there any way I can get around this or am I going to have to go back to the drawing board and redesign my classes?

Comment: Man that seems a very complicated design to me. Also I don't think you can use wildcards in classes or method declarations. Has that changed in Java 7?

Comment: About your main question, due to type erasure, you can´t return a class of the desired generic type at runtime. You could however work out something by passing a token type in the constructor.

Comment: I know about type erasure and I don't care. The generics are there for compile time type safety only and will save me dozens of casts while making mistakes less likely. What do you mean passing a token type in the constructor? Oh and Mister Smith - you definitely can use wildcards in classes and method declarations, it works fine in loads of other classes in the same project.

Comment: I meant you can't declare a class `public class Klazz<?>, but with extends it is allowed`; About the token, it is just a `Class<T>` instance so that you can return it at runtime, or fork new instances with `Class.newInstance`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously -- due to erasure -- there's only one `Class` object `Y.class` per class declaration `Y<F1, ..., FN>`. The type of this object is `Class<Y>`, `Y` being a raw type. To pass it of as a `Class<Y<A1, ..., AN>` you need to upcast and then downcast:

```
return (Class<Y<?, ?>>)(Object) Y.class;
```

The relevant JLS references you can find in a previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8127863/774444) to a similar question.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. Thanks! It feels like a hack, but if it makes the rest of the code more readable it may well be worth it.